# Issue with DALI interface circuit

Tags: opto-isolator, dali

I have a DALI interface board the circuit of which is shown below. This board was working so far but now the optocoupler in the circuit is not switching on DALI signals.

Dali interface circuit:
[image: DALI interface circuit]

The DALI bus is around 16v. I have tested the optocoupler separately by removing the DALI bus and giving external supply and it is switching properly.
Below are some scope shots were taken at different test points(Points are mentioned as the title of image)

Pin1_U2 to GND
[image: pin1toGND_U2]

Cathode D4 to GND
[image: CathodeD4toGND]

pin2 U2 to GND
[image: AnodeD2toGND]

DALI BUS
[image: DALI BUS]

DALI IN
[image: DALI IN]

Optocoupler is supposed to switch between 5v and 0v but as you can see output amplitude is very minimal. what could be the possible issue?

Comment: Is the indicator LED blinking between good'n'bright and off?

Comment: @Transistor Yes. As off time is very less, we cannot see led full off condition, but seeing as dimming/flickering..

Comment: The GND of the DALI IN and DALI OUT parts is galvanically separated from the part of the DALI bus. Between what test points are the last two scope shots taken? And where is the external power supply connected?

Comment: @altair Dali bus itself is + - signals.. Dali IN is taken between DALI_IN and gnd. External power supply is connected to +5v rail

Comment: Pin1_U2, Pin2_U2 and cathode D4  scope shots you need to take between pin3 diode bridge. DALI IN and DALI OUT  scope shots to take between GND.

Comment: @AltAir. Yes, actually its taken as you mentioned. sorry for the confusing naming

Comment: The D4 is broken.

Comment: @AltAir. Why are you saying D4 is broken. Could you give some info???

Comment: The voltage difference between the lower levels of oscillograms 'Cathode D4'  and 'Pin1_U2' is 2.4-1.6=0.8V. It's as if D4 is short-circuited or connected in reverse polarity. This is an assumption. The oscillogram from the anode D4 would be useful.